# Core Data - How to implement Child objects just like Java JPA @Embedded and @EntifyCollection

Tags: ios, core-data, jpa-2.0

I have a fairly common scenario on the Java server side where I have an Listing object and it contains an embedded ReturingPolicy object along with another embedded @EntityCollection of Shipping objects. Here is the Class:-

```
@Entity;
 public class Listing {
    @Id
    int id;

    @Embedded
    private ReturnPolicy returnPolicy;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<ShippingOption> shippingOptions;

}

@Embeddable
public class ReturnPolicy {
    private String details;
}

@Embeddable
public class Shipping {
    private String address;
}
```

I have to model the same in the iOS Core Data side. The problem is ReturnPolicy and Shipping objects don't have IDs as these are embedded object and embedded collection respectively. Its a design issue and I am not aware if Core data supports this. Any ideas on how to design it in iOS Core Data?

Comment: Are you asking if Core Data supports references to other core data objects and one-to-many relationships?

Comment: A Core Data `Listing` entity type could have direct references to instances of related `ReturnPolicy` and `Shipping` entity types. That *sounds* like what you're describing but I have no idea if that's "just like" the way Java does things.

Comment: Basically ReturnPolicy and Shipping objects don't have any unique identifier or ID as these objects are persisted as part of the Listing object on the Java server side. For example, fields of ReturnPolicy i.e details, will persist as part of the Listing table. But the collection will be persisted in Listing_Shipping table with Listing id and Shipping objects without any IDs. This is why I am not sure how to model this in the client side as there will be no ID or PK of these embedded objects.

Comment: Is this data that you'll be transferring to/from a server? And if so, what does the data look like in transit? JSON of some kind?

Comment: Here is the sample JSON. Note that the embedded objects don't have IDs.
"listing" : {
    "id" : 1,
"shippingOption" : [{"address":"NJ"}, {"address":"NY"}], "returnPolicy": {"details":"return is accepted"}
}